# Eclipse CDT include paths

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, eclipse-cdt

One thing that annoys me about Ecplise is that it seems like I need to explicitly add a path to include files for shared libraries that are 'built in' to my distro. No where else do I need a whole page of include paths to compile with gcc or g++ on Linux. For instance:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

Will need an explict path to /usr/include/gtk-2.0 and explicit paths to every include in the header.  However, I can compile the code with a simple gcc command and no -l switches and the pkgconfig settings to find the binary...

After searching the web, I have noticed that everyone seems to have this problem and no solution. But I feel in my gut that I have to be doing something wrong to add all of those paths explicitly in my gcc command...

I figured while I re-read the man page for gcc, I would fish for more info here...

Comment: Have you looked at your `INCLUDE` environment variable when running that compilation using the gtk header? I'd be amazed if `/usr/include/gtk-2.0` is NO in the multiple paths specified in your `INCLUDE` env-var.

Comment: In fact, in my entire environment, I have only two references to gtk at all, and both are resource dirs:
GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/myuser/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/myuser/.kde4/share/config/gtkrc-2.0
GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/myuser/.gtkrc:/home/myuser/.kde4/share/config/gtkrc

Comment: Also, I am running gtk-3 and gtk-2 side by side, and a simple command line compile and link hits 2 fine...it hits 3 too, if the pkgconfig line is pointing to 3....

Comment: It is not in a spec or alias'ed in either...